# Side effects of removing "width=device-width" from viewport meta tag when "initial-scale=1.0" is also set

Tags: css, viewport, meta-tags, meta

While the [`<meta name="viewport">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) tag is unstandardized, it "is respected by most mobile browsers due to de-facto dominance."

One downside of it not being a true web standard is detailed documentation is not as available as other standards. The [CSS Working Group](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#viewport-meta) has a specification for this, so that is what I am mainly using as an authoritative work.

My main question is:

### What would the perceived difference be between the following declarations?

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
```

Alternatively asked, what are the differences between these two [@viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport) CSS at-rules:

```css
/* Translated from <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> */
@viewport {
    zoom: 1.0;
    min-width: extend-to-zoom;
    max-width: 100vw;
}
```

```css
/* Translated from <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"> */
@viewport {
    zoom: 1.0;
    min-width: extend-to-zoom;
    max-width: extend-to-zoom;
}
```

---

How I arrived at those `@viewport` translations:

#### `width=device-width` to `min-width: extend-to-zoom; max-width: 100vw;`

The [CSS Device Adaptation Module Level 1 document](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#width-and-height-properties) states:

> The `width` and `height` viewport `<META>` properties are translated into `width` and `height` descriptors, setting the `min-width`/`min-height` value to `extend-to-zoom` and the `max-width`/`max-height` value to the length from the viewport.

They additionally give an [example](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#example-b13db30e):

> This `<META>` element:
>
> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=500, height=600">
> ```
>
> translates into:
>
> ```
> @viewport {
>     width: extend-to-zoom 500px;
>     height: extend-to-zoom 600px;
> }
> ```

The [`width` shorthand descriptor](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#width-desc) is described as:

> This is a shorthand descriptor for setting both `min-width` and `max-width`. One `<viewport-length>` value will set both `min-width` and `max-width` to that value. Two `<viewport-length>` values will set `min-width` to the first and `max-width` to the second.

So it stands to reason that `width: extend-to-zoom 500px;` is equivalent to `min-width: extend-to-zoom; max-width: 500px;`.

That only leaves the `100vw` part. Within [section 10.4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#width-and-height-properties), they explain:

> `device-width` and `device-height` translate to 100vw and 100vh respectively

So we can finally see how `width=device-width` is translated to `min-width: extend-to-zoom; max-width: 100vw;`.

#### `initial-scale=1.0` to `zoom: 1.0; width: extend-to-zoom;`

This one is a [verbatim example](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#example-d496fc24):

> This `<META>` element:
>
> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
> ```
>
> translates into:
>
> ```
> @viewport {
>     zoom: 1.0;
>     width: extend-to-zoom;
> }
> ```

---

The other question I have here is, **what *exactly* is the `extend-to-zoom` value?**

The [documentation on it](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#extend-to-zoom) and its [resolution procedure](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#resolve-extend-to-zoom) are difficult to grasp. If anyone can point me toward some further examples on this that'd be greatly appreciated.

---

In addition to everything above, I've put together a quick site - https://romellem.github.io/temp-site/viewport/ - to test some viewport configurations.

Namely:

- [content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"](https://romellem.github.io/temp-site/viewport/width_device-width_initial-scale_1.html)
- [content="initial-scale=1.0"](https://romellem.github.io/temp-site/viewport/initial-scale_1.html)

This may help with testing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Before we delve into what you're asking, let's review a little about why the `viewport` meta tag exists in the first place. Here's what I've gathered.

---

### Why do we need the `viewport` tag?

A viewport is an area where the web content can be seen. Usually, the *rendered page* (web content) is bigger than the viewport. As a result, we usually use scrollbars to see the hidden content (because the viewport can't display everything). [Quoted from CSS Device Adaptation Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/#intro):

> The narrow viewport is a problem for documents designed to look good
>   in desktop browsers. The result is that mobile browser vendors use a
>   fixed initial containing block size that is different from the
>   viewport size, and close to that of a typical desktop browser window.
>   In addition to scrolling or panning, zooming is often used to change
>   between an overview of the document and zoom in on particular areas of
>   the document to read and interact with.

In mobile devices (and other smaller devices), the [initial containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block) is usually larger than the viewport. For example, a mobile device that has a screen width of `640px` might have an initial containing block of `980px`. In this case, the initial containing block is shrunk to `640px` so that it can be fit into the mobile screen. This `640px` width (screen width) is what is called [***`initial-width`***](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#constraining-defs) of the viewport which will be pertinent to our discussion.

So.... Why do we need this `viewport` tag? Well, nowadays, we have [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) which allows us to design for mobile devices. However, this media query depends on the **actual** viewport's width. In mobile devices, the user agent automatically styles the initial viewport size to a different fixed one (usually larger than the initial viewport size). So if the viewport's width of a mobile device is fixed, the CSS rules we use in media queries won't be executed simply because the viewport's width never changes. Using the `viewport` tag, we can *control* the **actual** viewport's width (after being styled by the UA). [Quoted from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag):

> However, this mechanism is not so good for pages that are optimized for narrow screens using media queries — if the virtual viewport is 980px for example, media queries that kick in at 640px or 480px or less will never be used, limiting the effectiveness of such responsive design techniques.

*Note that the `viewport` tag can change the actual viewport's height too, not just the width*

---

### `viewport` tag's `width`

The `width` in a `viewport` tag is translated to `max-width` in the `@viewport` rule. When you declare the `width` as `device-width`, it is translated to `100%` in the `@viewport` rule. [Percentage value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block) is resolved based on the `initial-width` of the viewport. So if we're still using the above example, the `max-width` will resolve to a value of `640px`. As you've found out, this only specifies the `max-width`. The `min-width` will automatically be `extend-to-zoom`.

---

### `extend-to-zoom`

Your question was *what exactly is the value of extend-to-zoom*? From what I've gathered, it's the value that's used to support the viewport extending itself to fit the viewing area at a given zoom level. In other words, it's a viewport size value that changes based on the zooming value specified. An example? Given that the `max-zoom` value of the UA stylesheet is `5.0` and the `initial-width` is `320px`, `<meta name="viewport" content="width=10">` will resolve to an initial actual width of `64px`. This makes sense because if a device only has 320px and can only be zoomed `5x` the normal value, then the minimum viewport size would be `320px divided by 5`, which means showing only 64px at a time (**and not** `10px` because that would require zooming 32x!). This value will be used by the algorithm to determine how to extend (change) the `min-width` and `max-width` values, which will play a role in determining the actual viewport width.

---

### Putting it all together

So essentially, what's the difference between `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` and `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">`? Simply redo the steps of the algorithm ([this](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#resolve-extend-to-zoom) and [this](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#constraining-procedure)). Let's do the latter (the one without `width` attribute) first. (We will assume that the `initial-width` of the viewport is `640px`.)

- `width` is not set, this results in `max-width` and `min-width` being `extend-to-zoom` in the `@viewport` rule.
- `initial-scale` is `1.0`. This means that the `zoom` value is also `1.0`
- Let's [resolve `extend-to-zoom`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#resolve-extend-to-zoom). Steps:

  1. `extend-zoom = MIN(zoom, max-zoom)`. The `MIN` operation resolves to the value that is non-`auto`. Here, `zoom` is `1.0` and `max-zoom` is `auto`. This means that `extend-zoom` is `1.0`
  2. `extend-width  = initial-width / extend-zoom`. This is easy; divide 640 by 1. You get `extend-width` is equal to `640`
  3. Because `extend-zoom` is non-`auto`, we will skip to the second conditional. `max-width` is indeed `extend-to-zoom`, this means that `max-width` will be set to `extend-width`. Thus, `max-width = 640`
  4. `min-width` is also `extend-to-zoom`, this means setting `min-width` to `max-width`. We get `min-width = 640`
- After [resolving the non-`auto`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#resolve-px) (i.e. the `extend-to-zoom`) values for `max-width` and `min-width`. We can proceed to [the next procedure](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#resolve-initial-width-height). Because `min-width` or `max-width` is not `auto`, we will use the first `if` in the procedure, thus setting the initial actual viewport `width` to `MAX(min-width, MIN(max-width, initial-width))`, which equates to `MAX(640, MIN(640, 640))`. This resolves to `640` for your initial actual viewport `width`
- Moving on to [the next procedure](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#resolve-width). In this step, `width` is not `auto`. The value isn't changed and we end up with the actual viewport `width` of `640px`

Let's do the former.

- `width` is set, this results in `max-width` being `100%` (`640px` in our case) and `min-width` being `extend-to-zoom` in the `@viewport` rule.
- `initial-scale` is `1.0`. This means that the `zoom` value is also `1.0`
- Let's [resolve `extend-to-zoom`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#resolve-extend-to-zoom). If you follow the steps carefully (almost the same as above), you will end up with a `max-width` of `640px` and a `min-width` of `640px`.
- You can probably see the pattern now. We will get the actual viewport width of `640px`.

So what's the perceived difference? **Essentially none**. Both of them do the same thing. Hope my explanation helps ;-) If anything was amiss, do tell me.

Comment: This is great and is in line with what I was looking for. I'll mark this as the answer but I'd love some explanation of when you _could_ find differences. It seems like the main differences would be if you have initial content of some small with and an initial zoom not set to `1.0`, but I'm unsure on this.

Anyways, great answer, thanks!

Comment: @romellem Yes, one of the ways you can find a perceived difference when specifying the `viewport` tag attribute is when you do not specify the `initial-scale`. For example, when you write `<meta name="viewport" content="360px">`, you know that you aren't controlling the initial zoom level. As such, from my limited testing, the UA style always shrinks (through some procedure that might not be normative) the viewport. However, the actual viewport will always stay at a width of `360px`, regardless of the intial viewport size.

Comment: @romellem *Continuation*. However, when you write `<meta name="viewport" content="360px", initial-scale=1.0>`, you're making the `min-width` to `extend-to-zoom` and coupled with a `zoom` value, this will always resolve to the largest value between the initial viewport width divided by zoom value and the `max-width`. In the constraining procedure (section 7.2), you will see that the `width = MAX(min-width, MIN(max-width, initial-width))`. From my limited testing, my inference is that when the `max-width` specified is smaller than the...

Comment: @romellem *Continuation*. ... actual viewport width, it will always resolve to the initial viewport width. However, when the `max-width` value is larger than the initial viewport width, the minimum value would be the initial viewport width and the maximum value will be the, well, `max-width` value. The `extend-to-zoom` semantically makes sense because the `extend-to-zoom` on the `min-width` literally extends the value to the viewport width when the zoom is `1.0`. And this aligns with the answer above, that `extend-to-zoom` alters/extends/enlongates the `width` value **given** a zoom level.

Comment: @romellem Of course, it's not limited to just controlling the `initial-scale` attribute, but it's one of the ways to produce a perceived difference. *Revision to my first comment, the UA style can also zoom-in (not only shrink) the viewport when the device width is larger than 360px.*

Comment: "A viewport is an area where the web content can be seen".  On desktop we can resize the browser-window. Does this mean viewport width and height change? Is 'viewport' really the same as part of the browser window which can show user-content?

Comment: @PanuLogic The Net Ninja has a nice [video](https://youtu.be/JANETBQZJ8E) on this.