# CSS "@media only screen" only triggers when I resize window?

Tags: css, firefox

I have the following code on [this site](https://www.whitewaterwriters.com/) (it's Github Pages so you can see the repo [here](https://github.com/eQualityTime/whitewaterwriters-site/)):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 img {width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
 } 
 a.box {
  width: 100%;
  padding:14px 15px;
  font-size: 0.75em;
 }
}
```

On my mobile (iPhone 7 Plus), the screen width doesn't appear to be triggering:

[image]

Nor does it on Firefox's Responsive Design mode for iphone 7/8/9 Plus:

[image]

But If I make the firefox window one pizel bigger:

It suddenly works!

Additionaly - if I set my responsive browser window to exactly the same sizes as the iphone 6/7/8 - then it works fine. Which suggests that it's NOT the size - it's something about the iphone user-agent-string? Maybe?

[image]

What is going on and how to do I fix it?

Comment: I think there is interesting stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61410406/4698373) about the below answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a meta tag in the head, for the browser to handle viewport zooming correctly:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
```

Without the meta tag, the page is rendered at a higher screen width and then shrunk down to fit the device width. Hence the media queries will never be triggered.

More information on this can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag).

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in `<head>` tag of site
and it is better set standard `max-width:768px` instead of `600px` for `media-query`