# Chrome DevTools dimensions don't match ruler or device size

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I select a device size in the Chrome Device Toolbar, the dimensions labelled on my HTML elements don't match. The device here is 600x600, but hovering the `html` element in DevTools shows 980x980. The box shadow shows that the element isn't overflowing. My zoom is at 100%. Why don't the numbers match?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            html,
            body {
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px red inset;

                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;

                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by adding the following line inside `<head>`:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

The reason this happens is because using Chrome DevTools to simulate mobile device dimensions also simulates other aspects of a mobile device including a device pixel ratio of 2.0. The DPR value is locked to 2.0 in most device presets, and can be set manually with the `Dimensions: Responsive` option.

In the `...` menu there is an option to toggle showing the DPR.

[image]

[image]

References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61410406/3620725

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by setting the **browser zoom** to 100%

Comment: Yes I did figure this out. I just posted an answer with what I found

Comment: Nice to know what was your issue. Mine was pretty dumb ^^.

When you initialize your project with a toolbox (like create react app) the environment is configured and the <meta> is the following:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />